# How to get the first "<a>" element in the div

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a>a</a></li>
            <li><a>b</a></li>
            <li><a>c</a></li>
            <li><a>d</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a>e</a></li>
            <li><a>f</a></li>
            <li><a>g</a></li>
            <li><a>h</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a>i</a></li>
            <li><a>j</a></li>
            <li><a>k</a></li>
            <li><a>l</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            alert($("div a:first-child").text());    

            $("div").each(function(){
                alert($(this).find("a:first-child").text());
            });
        });    
    </script>
</html>
```

I want to get the first "" element in the div

But I have tried two ways like below  and cannot got it.

Can anybody teach me please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        alert($("div a:first-child").text());   

        $("div").each(function(){
            alert($(this).find("a:first-child").text());
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this, I think:

```
$("div a").first().text();
```

Comment: @Petah: You could always put a line like this in a loop or `.each` and go over every div you care about.